# ng-repeat binding with ng-model seems broken in AngularJS 1.3 but works in 1.2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was trying to upgrade my project to use `AngularJS 1.3` (RC0 as of writing) but a portion of my code that works in `1.2` but doesn't seem to work at all in `1.3`. Unless I misunderstood the concept of binding inside `ng-repeat`, which is also possible.  I have a list inside an `ng-repeat` which inside has a few inputs that are binded with `ng-model` and that use to work fine correctly in `1.2`. 
HTML code:

```
<fieldset id="order-fieldset1" ng-repeat="transaction in vm.transactions.orders.list">
    <legend>Transaction Order #{{$index+1}}</legend>
    <div>     
        <input type="number" name="nb_shares[]" ng-model="transaction.nb_shares" ng-change="vm.calculate()">
        <input type="number" name="prices[]" ng-model="transaction.price" ng-change="vm.calculate()">
        <input type="number" name="fees[]" ng-model="transaction.fee" ng-change="vm.calculate()">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Controller code:

```
// controller   
vm.transactions.orders = {
    list: [
        { nb_shares: null, fee: null, price: null }
    ]           
};

// public function 
vm.calculate = calculate;

function calculate() {
  // when I want to use it
  // AngularJS 1.2 returns proper value set of properties
  // but 1.3 always return null on all my properties
  var nbShares = vm.transactions.orders.list[0].nb_shares;

  console.debug(nbShares);
}
```

I've added the Firebug output of what's call from my `calculate()` function which has a console. Even though I typed 123, it shows my property `nb_shares` which is the one I'm changing, as `undefined`
[image]

**EDIT**
I found the problem and it's my custom validation directive that doesn't seem to be compliant with AngularJS 1.3, my input actually has this piece of code as well `validation="integer|required"` which is the culprit

Comment: Works fine here with 1.3.0 (beta-19) http://plnkr.co/edit/OFQw71?p=preview

Comment: Ah you're right PSL, though I forgot portion of my code, it's actually the `ng-change` that doesn't work. I updated my code..thanks for checking it

Comment: Are you sure you are typing in numeric value and it is not _"non numeric"_ it logs the value for me though... Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BC4ieL?p=preview Can you check if you can replicate

Comment: If I default a certain number like you did, let say 12, then I change the input to 123 and display console, it shows my property nb_shares as being `undefined`... BTW are you sure it's Angular 1.3 in your plunkr? I've never done plunkr myself but it doesn't seem to be using 1.3 just saying

Comment: in the index.html see the source url. i am using 1.3 beta 19. DO you have url for rc (i thought it is getting released next week or so)?

Comment: Added my firebug output if you could see my print screen... Angular 1.3 RC0 was released Friday (I think they weekly do it on Friday).. here's the Github log of https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-rc0-sonic-boltification-2014-08-29

Comment: Ahh damnit, nevermind I found my bug, and I feel stupid... it's my custom validation directive which I made that is not working correctly in `1.3` as soon as I remove it from the input it's all good as expected....ahhh :(

Comment: cool, didn't see that in your question though...

Comment: yes I removed it from the question, that's also why I feel stupid... Now I don't know if I should delete the question complete... Thanks a lot for your time though... at least now you know 1.3 is RC0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but this code may solve this issue:

```
<fieldset id="order-fieldset1" ng-repeat="transaction in vm.transactions.orders.list track by $index">
    <legend>Transaction Order #{{$index+1}}</legend>
    <div>     
        <input type="number" name="nb_shares[]" ng-model="transaction.nb_shares">
        <input type="number" name="prices[]" ng-model="transaction.price">
        <input type="number" name="fees[]" ng-model="transaction.fee">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but it doesn't fix it, actually the $index is working fine... I updated my question as it's more the `ng-change` that is problematic.. Thanks for your help